# building matplotlib on windows

Tags: python, visual-studio, matplotlib

I need to install matplotlib on Win 7 x64  (Python 2.7 x64). I have MS VS 10 installed (with MS C++ compiler).

When running

```
pip install matplotlib
```

I get this in pip.log:

...

```
cxxextensions.c

  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\PCbuild\amd64 freetype.lib z.lib /EXPORT:initft2font build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src/ft2font.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src/mplutils.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\CXX\cxxsupport.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\CXX\cxx_extensions.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\CXX\IndirectPythonInterface.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\CXX\cxxextensions.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\matplotlib\ft2font.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\ft2font.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\ft2font.pyd.manifest

LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'z.lib'

error: command '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\amd64\link.exe"' failed with exit status 1181
```

WTH is z.lib? It's not zlib for compression, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `z.lib` is a zlib library. But matplotlib offers [binary installers for Windows](http://matplotlib.org/downloads.html) so you don't need to install it from sources with `pip`.